# Query XML without namespace

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, xml

I can query XML, which has defined **xmlns** tag with **common table expression**

```
DECLARE @XML XML

SET @XML = 
'<NodeA xmlns="https://XYZ.xsd">
<NodeB verzePis="">
    <NodeC1 attrA="Hello" />
    <NodeC2 attrA="World" />
  </NodeB>
</NodeA>
'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'https://XYZ.xsd')

    SELECT
        r.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(50)') as SectionName,
        r.value('@attrA','NVARCHAR(250)') attrA
    FROM    @XML.nodes('/NodeA/NodeB/*') AS t(r);
```

But what if source XML does not contain any xmlns tag ? 
How can i workaround missing namespace ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just remove the `WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'https://XYZ.xsd')` part:

```
DECLARE @XML XML

SET @XML = 
'<NodeA>
<NodeB verzePis="">
    <NodeC1 attrA="Hello" />
    <NodeC2 attrA="World" />
  </NodeB>
</NodeA>
'

;--WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'https://XYZ.xsd')

    SELECT
        r.value('fn:local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(50)') as SectionName,
        r.value('@attrA','NVARCHAR(250)') attrA
    FROM    @XML.nodes('/NodeA/NodeB/*') AS t(r);
```

produces

```
+-------------+-------+
| SectionName | attrA |
+-------------+-------+
| NodeC1      | Hello |
| NodeC2      | World |
+-------------+-------+
```

Please note, [`WITH XMLNAMESPACES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms177607.aspx) does not create a common table expression, it just declares an *optional* namespace